# Find number of workers active on average any time during time range

Tags: java, sql, algorithm, datetime, date-range

TLDR: Looking to get the average number of workers (at any time) for each distinct group for a time range using the below SQL table. Either by using a SQL query or in moving the raw data from SQL to java and calculating it there.

I am trying to find the average number of workers in a group (for every group) that are available at any time within a particualar time range (let's say 8/5/2019-9/4/2019) with the given table below:

```
CREATE TABLE workers(
  group VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
  worker_name VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
  times tstzrange NOT NULL, 
);
```

To help clarify how the table works a bit: it is meant to represent worker machines that belong to specific groups of workers. I know that a worker has left the group when there is an end bound on the times field which is a tstzrange, otherwise if the worker is still in the group times is unbounded. A worker can be active for any length of time and “times” can span multiple days. A new row is only added when the worker is restarted, or a brand new worker is added. Workers can remain active between days and no new row is created for each day.

One problem that makes this more difficult is that workers may be added to and from the group throughout the course of single day, and sometimes are in for an hour or less. For example there may be 100-120 worker rows for a time range even though the average number of workers for any time in the time range (what I'm looking for) should be 4. Additionally I want the average for every single distinct group. Currently I'm using the query below to get the data, map it to objects in Java and then construct a solution from there.

```
select worker_name, lower(times) as start, upper(times) as end, group
from workers
where times && tstzrange('2019-08-05', '2019-09-04')
```

Most of the work is done in Java where I am making a map of each group -> all of the workers that belong to the group and their timestamps. I then am consolidating this list by seeing how many workers are active on each day during the period, and then averaging that over the entire timerange to find the average number of workers that are available in each group for the time period. It seems like this is a bit inefficient and not working as expected for all groups though, and I was wondering if I would be able to do this a better way directly in SQL (or efficiently in java). I've been working on the problem for a little while, and thought it seemed straight forward at first but am struggling to come up with a better solution. Hopefully someone with more experience doing this sort of thing can advise me on a good solution to this problem, and whether this should be handled directly in SQL or if some java logic is needed.

This is what I am using the map the data when I get it from SQL in Java to an object

```
public class WorkerMapping {

  private String group;
  private List<LocalDate> dates;

  public WorkerMapping(OffsetDateTime start, OffSetDateTime end, String group) {
    this.dates = start.toLocalDate().datesUntil(end.toLocalDate()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    this.group = group; 
  }

  // Getters and Setters
}
```

This is what I am using as a key for a HashMap. This allows each key and a date that it active to be a key in the map, which was helpful for summing up the occurences of each group on each day.

```
public class DateGroupKey {
  private String group;
  private LocalDate date;

  public DateGroupKey(String group, LocalDate date) {
      this.group = group;
      this.date = date; 
  }

  // Override equals and hash to be used as key for HashMap

}
```

Current logic to get average for each group:

```
    public HashMap<String, Double> getAverage(List<WorkerMapping> rows)
    {
        HashMap<String, Double> workerAverage = new HashMap<>();
        // Treemap is used so keys can be processed in order, and all groups are together. 
        TreeMap<DateGroupKey, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>((a, b) -> a.getGroup().equals(b.getGroup()) ?
                a.getDate().compareTo(b.getDate()) : a.getGroup().compareTo(b.getGroup()));
        for (HostsRow row : rows)
        {
            for (LocalDate date : row.getDates()) {
                DateGroupKey key = new DateGroupKey(row.getGroup(), date);
                if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                    map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
                } else {
                    map.put(key, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        List<DateGroupKey> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
        String currentGroup = keys.get(0).getGroup();
        int currentSum = 0;

        for (DateGroupKey key : keys ) {
            if (!key.getGroup().equals(currentGroup)) {
                workerAverage.put(currentGroup, Math.ceil(currentSum / 30.0));
                currentGroup = key.getGroup();
                currentSum = 0;
            }
            currentSum += map.get(key);
        }
        workerAverage.put(currentGroup, Math.ceil(currentSum / 30.0));
        return workerAverage;
    }
```

I am looking to receive a map of group to average workers for any time during a time range, either by using a better sql query or more efficient java.

Comment: I think your data setup is wrong. If worker is removed from the group, you will have to way of knowing that, as a group is just a single field that's going to change. You have to record work shifts history. Or does that table actually contain work shifts and not worker entities?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Since the times field is given as a tstzrange I'll know that the worker has left the group because there will be an upper bound on the range. Otherwise the range will be unbounded. I'll add this to the question as well to help clarify it

Comment: So is that, or is that not, actually a work shift? Also, what happens with these at night? Then, what happens if the next day worker is in same group? Will there be a new record in `workers`?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov The workers are representing worker machines and not actual workers. A record in workers can span multiple days or even the entire time range, and can be active all night. No new record is created for each day, a new record is only created if a worker is restarted after ending, or a brand new worker is started.